# Is $f(y)=\chi\!\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[q_{k},q_{k}+\frac{1}{4^{k}}\right]\right)(y)$ Riemann-Integrable on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Is $$f(y)=\chi\!\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[q_{k},q_{k}+\frac{1}{4^{k}}\right]\right)(y), \hspace{0.2cm} \{q_{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$$

Riemann-Integrable ?

Studying Integration, I came across the following problem that was unable to approach by any angle. I think there isn't an explicit answer, it may depens on how the $\{q_{k}\}$ are distributed.

I'd like to know wether the Riemann-Theory can solve this problem,

If so,I obvioulsy don't think there's a general method but there could be observations that have to be made to approach this types of problems.

Any hint,tip or solution, even using Negligible sets considerations would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: If the set of discontinuities is countable, it's Riemann integrable. Since the maximum cardinality of discontinuities is $2\times\aleph_0=\aleph_0,$ it's of measure zero, and hence Riemann integrable. Does this work? Maybe not; $f$ is not defined on a bounded domain.

Comment: Where do the $q_k$ live? Do you have any more information than that they're rational?

Comment: @AdrianKeister No, just that they are rational, that's why I don't expect an exactly answer but just dependant on $q_{k}$

Comment: Riemann integrable where? You haven't specified enough information.

Comment: What does Riemann integrable on $\mathbb R$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

As I asked in a comment, Riemann integrable (RI) where? Unless you specify a closed bounded interval, the question doesn't make much sense. (Now you say RI on $\mathbb R,$ but what does that mean?)

**Edit** The below is edited from the original, where I misunderstood the hypotheses to imply $\{q_k\}=\mathbb Q.$

There are certainly examples where the choice of $q_k$ lead to counterexamples: Assume $\{q_k\}$ is all of $\mathbb Q.$ Then the resulting $f$ is not RI on any interval $[a,b]$ with $b-a>1/3.$

Proof: Suppose $b-a>1/3.$ Let $E=(\bigcup [q_k,q_k+1/4^k])\cap [a,b].$ Then $m(E) \le \sum 4^{-k} = 1/3.$ Thus $m([a,b]\setminus E)=b-a - m(E) >0.$ At every $x\in [a,b]\setminus E,$ we have $f(x) = 0.$ But this $x$ is the limit of a sequence of rationals, along which $f=1.$ Thus $f$ is discontinuous at each such $x.$ By the Lebesgue criterion, $f$ is not RI on $[a,b].$

Comment: I'm sorry you are right, i'm gonna edit the question, which initially was on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Just thinking, your counterexample is true if $q_{k} $ belongs in $[0,1]$ is that right? . As mentioned the enumeration is arbitrary

Comment: No matter what the enumeration is, the $f$ in my answer is not RI on $[0,1].$

Comment: Why $x$ is the limit of a sequence of rationals along which $f = 1 ?$ I don't understand either why i can found a sequence of rationals for every $x$, i'm basically saying that are dense in $[0,1] ?$

Comment: I was assuming $\{q_k\}$ was all the rationals. It's not?

Comment: No, they are an enumeration of rationals, a subset of $\mathbb{Q} $, with no specific location

Comment: The flaw in your proof is that there's no reason to assume even an uncountably many $q_k$ in $[0,1].$

Comment: +1 for showing that $f$ could be discontinuous at every point in a finite interval.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I was not assuming uncountably many $q_k\in [0,1].$ That would be a little silly, as the set $\{q_k\}$ is countable. Also I did not show discontinuity at every point; I showed for every point in $[0,1] \setminus E$ (with my assumption that the $q_k$ enumerated all of $\mathbb Q.$)

Comment: @zhw. Oh, you're right. You've shown that $f$ is discontinuous at every irrational number in $[a,b]\setminus E,$ which, in a wide enough interval, is enough to pick up positive measure and make $f$ not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

**Claim:** $f(y)$ is Lebesgue integrable.

**Proof:** Note that, for any $q_j$ and $q_k,$ we have that $m([q_j,q_j+4^{-j}]\cup[q_k,q_k+4^{-k}])\le 4^{-j}+4^{-k},$ since the intervals might overlap; if the intervals do not overlap, we get equality. Let
$$U=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[q_{k},q_{k}+\frac{1}{4^{k}}\right]. $$
So we have
$$
\int\chi\!\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[q_{k},q_{k}+\frac{1}{4^{k}}\right]\right)(y)\,dm=m(U)
\le\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^k}
=\frac13
<\infty.\qquad \text{QED.}
$$

So is it Riemann integrable? Well, the easiest theorem to use, when applicable, is the Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem. However, on an infinite domain, the Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem is not applicable. We do know that if the Riemann integral exists, then it is equal to the Lebesgue integral. And since the Lebesgue integral has been proven to exist by being finite, if the Riemann integral exists, it is finite. However, it is possible, as per zhw.'s answer, for $f$ to be discontinuous at every point in a closed and bounded interval.

Therefore, my current conclusion is that there is no conclusion. I think the answer is highly dependent on the location of the $q_k$'s.

Hopefully, the ideas in this answer will stimulate someone else to a full, correct answer.

Comment: By the way [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral?wprov=sfti1) is only defined on compact intervals.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Well, in this case I'm thinking that we're likely considering an improper Riemann integral such as on an infinite interval.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes we would like to do some consideration on an infinite interval

Comment: @AdrianKeister I'm sorry, I think I get the point if the intervals don't overlap, what about they do? As you mention it may happen

Comment: I don't know for sure. I wonder if there's a theorem that says if you have a function with countably many discontinuities on any bounded interval, and the corresponding Lebesgue integral exists on the entire real axis, that therefore the Riemann integral exists.

Comment: Could be nice, but i think it's easier think a counterexample than a real proof. Never heard of it.

Comment: "for any $q_j$ and $q_k,$ we have that $m([q_j,q_j+4^{-j}])+m([q_k,q_k+4^{-k}])\le 4^{-j}+4^{-k},$ since the intervals might overlap;" No, equality always holds. Perhaps you were thinking of something else.

Comment: The discontinuities are countable? No, they are uncountable. You may wish to look at my answer. Also, the intervals in question are never pairwise disjoint, no matter what the enumeration of the $q_k$ is.

Comment: @zhw You're right, I should have been more precise I was thinking of $m([q_j, q_j+4^{-j}]\cup[q_k, q_k+4^{-k}])\le 4^{-j}+4^{-k},$ which could have inequality if the intervals overlap. I'll edit.

Comment: As per the comment in your answer, because the $q_k$ are not necessarily all of $\mathbb{Q},$ they can be disjoint.

Comment: @zhw: You're right in that there *could* be uncountably many points of discontinuities. But I think, depending on the $q_k$'s, that there might not be. Sounds like there isn't enough information to go on.